# Android how to start activity without intent or backround

Tags: android, android-intent

Suppose I have two activities A and B activity A which contains a button I want to start Activity B when I press Button without intent.

Comment: the only way to do that is using intents

Comment: May I know Why?, are you inventing something??

Answer (score 5):

According the Oficial Documentation:

An intent is an abstract description of an operation to be performed. It can be used with `startActivity` to launch an `Activity`, `broadcastIntent` to send it to any interested `BroadcastReceiver` components, and `startService(Intent)` or `bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int)` to communicate with a background Service.

An `Intent` provides a facility for performing late runtime binding between the code in different applications. Its most significant use is in the launching of activities, where it can be thought of as the glue between activities. It is basically a passive data structure holding an abstract description of an action to be performed.

So you have to use it to open activities with no exceptions or workarounds, if you do that, you are ignoring the entire system architecture.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to start an activity from anotherone without an intent.

Answer (score 4):

If the reason of **not** using `Intent` that you don't want the the user to **re-enter** the previous activity

You can use `finish()` to finish that activity intent after you done work with

```
if(currentUser == null){
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,StartActivity.class));
    finish();
}
```

So user will be unable to back again

> If you want to do some code while the activity is finishing

You can use `onDestroy()` override method, Sometimes it can also be called if the activity is being killed by the android itself so you can add

**isFinishing()** function

Inside `onDestroy()` method which checks whether the application is closing by the call `finish()` returning `true` or otherwise by anything else returning `false` then you can easily specify your code for each situation.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if(isFinishing()){
        // Activity is being destroyed by the function `finish()`
        // What to do...
    }else{
        // Activity is being destroyed anonymously without `finish()`
        // What to do...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your activity inside a Fragment and start the fragment fromo the button.

Answer (score 2):

These are the possible ways to start any Activity

**1st**

```
startActivity(new Intent(Activity_A.this, Activity_B.class));
```

**2nd**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_A.this, Activity_B.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**3rd**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_A.this, Activity_B.class);
startActivityForResult(intent,code);
```